# Why do I not need to specify OS version when cross-compiling?

Tags: linux, go, compilation, cross-compiling

Preface: my experience cross-compiling code is minimal, and I'm mostly coming at this from a golang background

I can cross-compile golang like so `GOOS=<OS> GOARCH=<architecture> go build <source-file>`
Where OS could be something like "linux" or "windows".
Why do I not need to specify which version of linux or windows (or whatever else)? Surely e.g. linux has changed over the years and I should need to specify a version if it depends on it.

I guess another way to phrase this question is, if I compile some code on my linux machine, would that run on all older version of linux? Surely not

A related question: I suppose OS here means OS in the sense of the kernel, not OS in the wider sense it is sometimes used to mean the whole GNU+linux system etc.

Comment: You do not have to specify the version because you cannot crosscompile to old OSs because nobody uses old OSs because that would be terrible dangerous. Thats why there is no flag to select Windows 95.

Comment: @Jay - _if I compile some code on my linux machine, would that run on all older version of linux? Sure not_ - You're probably right regarding _all_, but you'd also probably be surprised on how many older versions and even more newer versions it runs.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Go Wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MinimumRequirements), the minimum supported Linux Kernel (`GOARCH` `amd64` or `386`) is:

> 2.6.23 or later

so basically any Linux distribution from [late 2007 onwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_version_history).

Other Linux architectures (`arm*`, `mips*`, `s390x`) supported kernel versions can be found [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Linux).